# ssl received a record that exceed the maximum permissible length error in php curl

Tags: php, ssl, php-curl

Am getting an error message `SSL RECEIVED A RECORD THAT EXCEEDED THE MAXIMUM PERMISSIBLE LENGTH`, when uploading image using php curl. I have checked my SSL, is working properly and also other upload function that doesn't use curl is working as well.

Here is my php curl code.

```
<php 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/upload_gallery.php");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVar);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".hash('sha256', uniqid('', true))));
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    $pms = json_decode($out,true);
```

And also i have attached my full php code here https://hastebin.com/aqoxufoyoy.xml

Comment: This error is typically if a HTTPS request is made to a destination which does not support HTTPS. Are you sure that you are getting no error with other clients with __the same URL__ and from __the same host__? If this is the case could you please provide the real URL to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It's same host, few days back it was working fine, i didn't even make any changes to my code.

Comment: If it was working fine with the same code then why do you assume that the problem is in your code? Likely the problem is in the server setup which you don't show. Again, can you access the __exact__ same URL with some different client running at the same host as your PHP code?